# How do I search string without case sensitivity in Humio?

Tags: search, case-insensitive

For instance, I'd like to match "error" with "ERROR," "Error," and of course "error." What should my query be? Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.humio.com/language-syntax/#regex-filters

Comment: Thank you! Why not answering but downgrading!? :) I didn't have time to read the doc, and did not find any straight answer from SO either.

Comment: Please refer to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Questions where users haven't made an effort to research the answer should be downvoted—that's what downvoting is for. As you admit, it was clear you hadn't taken the time to try to research the answer yourself before asking.

Comment: Understood. I think SO should allow for "quick favor" category where user  could ask "the world" for a "quick tip." I spent a bit of time to read the doc; but sometimes I felt it's faster to ask than digging thru to find a specific syntax.

Comment: I'm sure it is faster to ask, but SO isn't meant to be used for outsourcing research or googling.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [above link](https://docs.humio.com/language-syntax/#regex-filters), this regex works for me:
/ERROR/i